# Seeking high resolution real-color (RGB imagery) dataset?

Tags: data, united-states, resolution, rgb

Specifically interested in the the South Florida region, USA. The aim is to pull up high quality aerials to detect manholes and wellheads from space! These things can typically be half a foot to a foot in diameter.

Comment: Are you looking for free data? Please [edit] your question with that information. FYI, [opendata.se] is a good place to ask for free data sets, and sometimes you'll get suggestions about non-free data sources as well.

Comment: This dataset says it has 1-foot resolution orthoimagery for the US: https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5825a0c2e4b01fad86db66cc. If the "browse image" is an accurate preview, parts of the southern tip of the Florida mainland is missing.

Comment: Did you consider Nearmap? https://www.nearmap.com/us/en/products/orthographic-view-nearmap-vertical